RtmRegisterEntity Access violation
Summary
I try to implement this example: Register with the Routing Table Manager, but I get an error:
Exception has occurred: W32/0xC0000005
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCFACEBCE4 (rtm.dll) in clash-rs.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

I also get a bit confused about windows::Win32::NetworkManagement::Rras::RTM_ENTITY_ID and the embedded Anonymous, RTM_ENTITY_ID_0_0 stuff.  Is that due to the definition being a union?
typedef struct _RTM_ENTITY_ID {
  union {
    struct {
      ULONG EntityProtocolId;
      ULONG EntityInstanceId;
    };
    ULONGLONG EntityId;
  };
} RTM_ENTITY_ID, *PRTM_ENTITY_ID;

and that is how it looks like mapping to Rust?
I'm not sure if it's related to the pointer issue.
Crate manifest
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
windows = { version = "0.58", features = [
    "Win32_Networking_WinSock",
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_NetworkManagement_Rras",
]}

Crate code
let address_family = match dest {
        IpNet::V4(_) => AF_INET,
        IpNet::V6(_) => AF_INET6,
    };

    let rtm_reg_handle: HANDLE = null_mut();
    let mut rtm_entity_info = RTM_ENTITY_INFO::default();
    let mut rtm_regn_profile = RTM_REGN_PROFILE::default();

    rtm_entity_info.RtmInstanceId = 0;
    rtm_entity_info.AddressFamily = address_family.0;
    rtm_entity_info
        .EntityId
        .Anonymous
        .Anonymous
        .EntityProtocolId = PROTO_IP_RIP.0.try_into().unwrap();
    rtm_entity_info
        .EntityId
        .Anonymous
        .Anonymous
        .EntityInstanceId = protocol_id(
        PROTO_TYPE_UCAST,
        PROTO_VENDOR_ID,
        PROTO_IP_RIP.0.try_into().unwrap(),
    );
    let rv = unsafe {
        RtmRegisterEntity(
            &mut rtm_entity_info,
            null_mut(),
            None,
            false,
            &mut rtm_regn_profile,
            rtm_reg_handle as *mut _,
        )
    };

    if rv != ERROR_SUCCESS.0 {
        let err = unsafe { GetLastError().to_hresult().message() };
        error!("failed to register entity: {}", err);
        return Err(new_io_error(err));
    }


I would assume its from passing null for the handle parameter. The docs usually mention if null is allowed, and its not mentioned for that parameter. Judging from the Rust signature, you probably want let mut rtm_reg_handle: isize = 0; and pass it as &mut rtm_reg_handle.

this didn't help. also

The resulting pointer has the address 0.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.null_mut.html
I wonder if there's any difference writing it that way

We cannot see what you changed but I assume you failed to pass a reference. Make sure you follow kmdreko's instructions to the letter.

ty. I put the changed code with edits. this is still failing

actually, my bad. after making this change the fn call passed. I have another one down below that needs change too. the suggestion actually worked.

can i ask one more - what is the difference with the 0: isize and the return value of null_mut() as they both seem to be an address pointing to zero?

Judging from the docs, the handle parameter should not be null. Going off the Rust signature you want to do this instead:
let mut rtm_reg_handle: isize = 0;

...

let rv = unsafe {
    RtmRegisterEntity(
        ...
        &mut rtm_reg_handle,
    )
};


what is the difference with the 0: isize and the return value of null_mut() as they both seem to be an address pointing to zero?

The function is not expecting a null pointer, which is what null_mut() creates. What is happening above is we are creating a variable on the stack and passing a pointer to it (which won't be null). The actual value of the rtm_reg_handle doesn't matter, it could be 42069 for all it matters since it just needs to exist and the RtmRegisterEntity call will overwrite it.
